# PHP/ CakePHP and friendsofCake/CRUD --> authentication

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a web application built in PHP, running behind Apache. The application uses its own security logic and sets $_SESSION['username'] to a valid username if a user logs into its web interface

The original developer has moved on, and I am adding APIs to this app so that people can develop 3rd party apps that connect. The API layer uses FriendsOfCake CRUD https://github.com/friendsofcake/crud

The API are working great, and now I want to add authentication.  I know REST APIs should be stateless etc. However in this application, the people who can use the APIs MUST also be able to log into the web console.

Given that the core PHP app is already handling authentication and sets $_SESSION, I want my CRUD APIs to check if $_SESSION['user'] user is set.

The logic will be as follows:
a) Do a http://server/login.php POST with credentials (not via API layer)
b) Then do http://server/api/

If a) is not done, b) won't work. That is my goal.

How do I get access to $_SESSION ? When I try and access it in the API controller for one of the APIs, it is not defined. It is however available to the PHP apps that the current app uses.

Note that the APIs and the backend app are running on the same server like so:
web/ --> server php code
web/api --> API code (via FoC CRUD)

Comment: `http://server/login.php` is obviously not part of the same (cakephp) app. Step one is to use the same session cookiename.

Comment: Okay thanks. I assumed PHP would treat them to be part of the same app and codebase as the apis are part of the main app.

Comment: @AD7six, my requirement is a little simplified. as it turns out the server/login.php sets a cookie - lets called it MYCOOKIE. I want to make sure the cakephp layer is able to read it to. Is this the right way to do it?

Configure::write('Session', array('cookie'=>MYCOOKIE)) inside api/app/Config/core.php? If so, how do I go about rejecting all API requests if this cookie is not set? thanks